# IIS 8.5 on Server 2012 R2 stops responding after a time

Tags: http-status-code-404, webapi, iis-8.5

I recently updated a server from 2008 R2 to 2012 R2 that hosts a few MVC sites and a Web API.  After deployment, everything seems to work fine for a few days before the web API seems to fail.  It returns a 404 for all requests to the API from the failure forward.  The parent MVC site seems to continue working fine.

A few things:

- The web API is hosted as a web application inside a parent website within IIS.
- This is a 4.6.2 framework site and API.
- I would prefer it to be its own site but I don't control this.
- It seems to stop at roughly the same time when it occurs - around 2:35 AM
- The only route defined by the web API is a GET

I've checked the event log as well as IIS logs.  The event log doesn't reflect anything during these times and the IIS logs just show a 404 response. Resetting IIS/AppPools/etc... don't fix the API nor does restarting the machine.  In fact, the only thing that seems to fix it temporarily is a VS publish over top of site.

I suspect something to do with MSDeploy but have nothing concrete.  Does anyone have any ideas on where to look or what to look for? I feel it must be something to do with the server configuration as we've never seen this problem prior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out the problem.  Our project uses NLog with the config specified to create a new log file daily.  Something within either NLog or IIS recently decided not to play nicely together.  A temporary fix was to turn off the daily file creation from within NLog.  Since making this change, the site has stayed up consistently for the past week.

[This](https://forums.iis.net/post/2109545.aspx) post is what got me checking into NLog as a possible culprit.